# PHP usort() not accurate?

Tags: php, usort

I have a multi-dimensional array. Inside each array, their is a sub value called "elo-rating". I want to sort my array based on this sub value.

So I take my array, called `$newRanks` and run it through the following:

```
uasort($newRanks, create_function(
    '$b, $a', 'return $a["elo_rating"] - $b["elo_rating"];'
));
```

After running through that code, my array returns as follows:

```
array:52 [
  "3-1154" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 1154
    "elo_matches" => 8
    "elo_rating" => 1224.47797881
  ]
  "3-205" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 205
    "elo_matches" => 11
    "elo_rating" => 1207.86593741
  ]
  "3-1" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 1
    "elo_matches" => 17
    "elo_rating" => 1206.60264689
  ]
  "3-285" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 285
    "elo_matches" => 4
    "elo_rating" => 1187.31524255
  ]
  "3-259" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 259
    "elo_matches" => 4
    "elo_rating" => 1173.02391767
  ]
  "3-12689" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 12689
    "elo_matches" => 4
    "elo_rating" => 1167.46830619
  ]
  "3-1603" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 1603
    "elo_matches" => 13
    "elo_rating" => 1153.3060092
  ]
  "3-16" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 16
    "elo_matches" => 7
    "elo_rating" => 1146.65083202
  ]
  "3-1609" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 1609
    "elo_matches" => 3
    "elo_rating" => 1122.679103
  ]
  "3-333" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 333
    "elo_matches" => 5
    "elo_rating" => 1112.56694511
  ]
  "3-10030" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 10030
    "elo_matches" => 4
    "elo_rating" => 1091.27782914
  ]
  "3-378" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 378
    "elo_matches" => 9
    "elo_rating" => 1082.0354022
  ]
  "3-6107" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 6107
    "elo_matches" => 5
    "elo_rating" => 1059.74850166
  ]
  "3-5179" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 5179
    "elo_matches" => 3
    "elo_rating" => 1046.60181418
  ]
  "3-1476" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 1476
    "elo_matches" => 9
    "elo_rating" => 1038.88789903
  ]
  "3-70" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 70
    "elo_matches" => 8
    "elo_rating" => 1038.63959146
  ]
  "3-303" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 303
    "elo_matches" => 7
    "elo_rating" => 1039.26666217
  ]
  "3-59" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 59
    "elo_matches" => 1
    "elo_rating" => 1033.78309445
  ]
  "3-1017" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 1017
    "elo_matches" => 4
    "elo_rating" => 1002.79264647
  ]
  "3-632" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 632
    "elo_matches" => 3
    "elo_rating" => 1002.2039368
  ]
  "3-177" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 177
    "elo_matches" => 4
    "elo_rating" => 994.838857477
  ]
  "3-12466" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 12466
    "elo_matches" => 4
    "elo_rating" => 994.761652125
  ]
  "3-9725" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 9725
    "elo_matches" => 7
    "elo_rating" => 994.520367143
  ]
  "3-1593" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 1593
    "elo_matches" => 4
    "elo_rating" => 987.448354356
  ]
  "3-78" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 78
    "elo_matches" => 16
    "elo_rating" => 984.927509938
  ]
  "3-20837" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 20837
    "elo_matches" => 4
    "elo_rating" => 981.533602402
  ]
  "3-25" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 25
    "elo_matches" => 3
    "elo_rating" => 977.651701927
  ]
  "3-2056" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 2056
    "elo_matches" => 8
    "elo_rating" => 978.374247502
  ]
  "3-14300" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 14300
    "elo_matches" => 9
    "elo_rating" => 958.218292232
  ]
  "3-16900" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 16900
    "elo_matches" => 3
    "elo_rating" => 957.66758785
  ]
  "3-5" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 5
    "elo_matches" => 3
    "elo_rating" => 955.441682773
  ]
  "3-11793" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 11793
    "elo_matches" => 3
    "elo_rating" => 956.118019821
  ]
  "3-23" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 23
    "elo_matches" => 1
    "elo_rating" => 950.0
  ]
  "3-160" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 160
    "elo_matches" => 6
    "elo_rating" => 946.346810828
  ]
  "3-11882" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 11882
    "elo_matches" => 3
    "elo_rating" => 943.113557791
  ]
  "3-178" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 178
    "elo_matches" => 3
    "elo_rating" => 940.38037017
  ]
  "3-2113" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 2113
    "elo_matches" => 3
    "elo_rating" => 940.343382565
  ]
  "3-1334" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 1334
    "elo_matches" => 2
    "elo_rating" => 923.336202927
  ]
  "3-184" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 184
    "elo_matches" => 2
    "elo_rating" => 920.326252901
  ]
  "3-2162" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 2162
    "elo_matches" => 2
    "elo_rating" => 917.932985501
  ]
  "3-2058" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 2058
    "elo_matches" => 6
    "elo_rating" => 905.641833006
  ]
  "3-1951" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 1951
    "elo_matches" => 2
    "elo_rating" => 906.136056131
  ]
  "3-1749" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 1749
    "elo_matches" => 2
    "elo_rating" => 905.570092295
  ]
  "3-15296" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 15296
    "elo_matches" => 2
    "elo_rating" => 901.02829192
  ]
  "3-11684" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 11684
    "elo_matches" => 2
    "elo_rating" => 901.02829192
  ]
  "3-940" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 940
    "elo_matches" => 2
    "elo_rating" => 899.735074733
  ]
  "3-12235" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 12235
    "elo_matches" => 2
    "elo_rating" => 900.0
  ]
  "3-2957" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 2957
    "elo_matches" => 2
    "elo_rating" => 900.0
  ]
  "3-14959" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 14959
    "elo_matches" => 2
    "elo_rating" => 894.798068073
  ]
  "3-779" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 779
    "elo_matches" => 5
    "elo_rating" => 874.675970857
  ]
  "3-110" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 110
    "elo_matches" => 4
    "elo_rating" => 849.309123925
  ]
  "3-5837" => array:4 [
    "league_id" => 3
    "user_id" => 5837
    "elo_matches" => 4
    "elo_rating" => 821.601462523
  ]
]
```

If you look closely at this resulting array, you'll notice that its not exactly sorted properly. For instance, it puts `1039.26666217` below both `1038.63959146` and `1038.88789903`.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: omg.. where did you find an example that uses `create_function` ? Never go there again =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning decimal values from your function, which the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) warns against.

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second. Note
>   that before PHP 7.0.0 this integer had to be in the range from
>   -2147483648 to 2147483647.
>
> Caution Returning non-integer values from the comparison function,
>   such as float, will result in an internal cast to integer of the
>   callback's return value. So values such as 0.99 and 0.1 will both be
>   cast to an integer value of 0, which will compare such values as
>   equal.

Change your function to return an integer to fix the issue.

```
uasort($newRanks, create_function(
    '$b, $a', 'return ($a["elo_rating"] > $b["elo_rating"])?-1:1;'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. You're using `create_function()` which uses `eval()` internally, which is a gaping security hole, and unnecessary to boot. Just use an actual anonymous function.
2. Your function arguments are backwards.
3. Willem Renzema raises a valid point about the implicit cast of the return value, but I don't like the solution.

So:

```
$epsilon = 0.000000001;
uasort(
  $newRanks,
  function($a,$b)use($epsilon}{
    $diff = $a["elo_rating"] - $b["elo_rating"];
    if( abs($diff) < $epsilon ) { return 0; }
    else if( $diff > 0 ) { return 1; }
    else { return -1; }
  )
);
```

Where `$epsilon` is a value chosen specifically for this comparison where you consider any `$diff` smaller than that to be an equivalence, aka float/rounding error.

See: [What is the most effective way for float and double comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)